# Firebase Cloud Messaging Cannot parse topic name

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to subscribe to a topic in my iOS app, but keep getting the error:

```
<FIRMessaging/WARNING> Cannot parse topic name /topics/pets/cnlLksAxmdYPkDjEftDwZjFwvDw2_coffee. Will not subscribe.
```

The code I'm trying to subscribe with is this:

```
FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/pets/\(name)")
```

where `name` is the last part of the topic you see in the error.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? I've already confirmed Firebase messaging is correctly receiving notifications and all.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `/` character is not an allowed character for a *topic name*.

Characters allowed are:

- a-z
- A-Z
- 0-9
- `-`, `_`, `.`, `~`, `%`

I can confirm these are the only allowed characters by testing in *Android* with a topic name of `pets/123asd` and the logs shown:

```
Invalid topic name: Pets/123asd does not match the allowed format [a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]{1,900}
```

For iOS, the prefix `/topics/` is needed and is still valid. The invalid characters only apply to the *topic name* you include after the prefix.

Comment: Hi @MarksCode. Just wanted to see if you managed to make it working after changing the topic name?

Comment: weird as Firebase give an example topic of `/topics/news` [in their example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging) AND their log message when you just use a plain topic name like `news` they give a console error: `<FIRMessaging/WARNING> WARNING. Topic name news should be prefixed with /topics/ as /topics/news`

Comment: @NSTJ Interesting. I didn't notice that in the docs. I'll try to look around and see what I find about it. My guess though is that maybe `news` is possibly a predefined topic. Don't know if that's possible though. Will update my answer after checking.

Comment: aha - @AL. I didn't actually use `news`, I used my own topic name (it was an arbitrary integer) but used `news` as a commonly grokked example :)  Side note - my issue ultimately turned out to be the fact that it takes in the order of *hours* for a new topic to be created and show up on the console, in case anyone ends up here in a similar situation

Comment: @NSTJ So I've done some digging and my answer still stands correct. The format for subscribing in iOS does need the `/topics/` before the topic name. However, the topic name itself shouldn't have any invalid characters. Yup. It takes usually a few hours or a day at most for the topics to show up in the Firebase Notifications Console. :)

Comment: all good!  Perhaps update your answer to reflect the difference between _topic name_ and the _prefix_ to the topic name (ie: `topic/`) as my reading from your answer is that you can't have a `/` in either (not to detract from your answer - it helped me!   Cheers)

Comment: @AL. so regarding topics, we cant use white space between names, example: a topic called "hello world", we cant use that?

Comment: @PeterHaddad Looks like an empty space is also an invalid character. I tried it on Android it gave me a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.fcm.test.app: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid topic name: Hello World does not match the allowed format [a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]{1,900}`

Comment: yes me too! thats why im shocked, alright thank you for answering

Comment: For assert() purposes, you can check that a topic name is valid with the following: `BOOL validTopic = ([topic.lowercaseString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890._-~%%"] invertedSet]].location == NSNotFound);//Double '%%' is intentional to avoid format identifier issues`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pick a string for a topic that contains un-allowed characters then you need to make the string a raw string.

Ex=> `String str=r'something@gmail.com'`

Here string 'str' contains a '@' character which is not valid for the FCM topic but by making it a raw string, it can be successfully parsed.