# Getting "MissingToken" when using BatchAdd to add subscribers to a FCM topic

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a new topic in my Firebase structure, so I need do add several IID's to several different topic.

I find in Firebase documentation the BatchAdd process, in theory is quite simple, but not works for me.

My code below, using php

https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd/

```
$headers = array(
 ‘Authorization: key = XYZ’,
 ‘Content-Type: application/json’
);

$fields = array(
 “to”=>”/topics/movies”,
 “registration_tokens”=>array(
 “ABC”,
 “DEF”
 )
);
```

Response:

Code: 400

```
{“error”:”MissingToken”}
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

Screen Shots V2

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it just a typo in the post or is your Authorization header missing a closing `'`?

Comment: @AL.Thanks, man, a typo ...just added

Comment: The request contents looks good. Are you using valid tokens when testing this on your end? Could you try sending the request via Postman and see if the response is still the same?

Comment: @AL.I just added two screen shot from postman

Comment: Thanks. [`/` is not a valid topic name character.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43059877/4625829). Could you try removing the last `/`? Also, for the Authorization header, try only adding the key (without `key = `) and try it without the spaces in between (e.g. `key=<key>`)

Comment: @AL., new screen shots added, something, same error ... I think this call mat have some bug

Comment: I tested on my end, [works as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccqqk.png)

Comment: @AL. would you send a print of your header?

Comment: @AL Hi dear ... thanks for the patience, I was calling https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd/ with a "/" ate the end of the url, that was the mistake! I remove the "/" and daaaaah, now is working.

Answer (score 0):

I was calling the URL with a "/" at the end!

The url is: https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd